# How to verify right guess from a list after user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know how the user input will satisfy the compiler!

I tried: "gussing != guessing_list[1] or .......gussing != guessing_list[5]" but failed

```
guessing_list = ["New York", "Mumbai", "Brooklyn", "Tokyo", "Peris"]
gussing = ""
gussing_counting = 0
gussing_limits = 4
gussing_range = False

while gussing != guessing_list[1:5] and not(gussing_range):
    if gussing_counting < gussing_limits:
        gussing = str(input("Enter Your dream city: "))
        gussing_counting += 1
    else:
        gussing_range = True
if gussing_range:
    print("You're out or range!")
else:
    print("You got your dream city!")'
```

I want that if user inputs "Brooklyn" in the given range then the output must say "You got your dream city!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if a value is present in a sequence (such as a list or a string), you should use the `in` keyword. I think what you are looking for is this:

```
while gussing not in guessing_list and not gussing_range :
```

Note that your `while` loop could be simplified to:

```
while gussing not in guessing_list and gussing_counting < gussing_limits:
    gussing = str(input("Enter Your dream city: "))
    gussing_counting += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dream_city_list = ["New York", "Mumbai", "Brooklyn", "Tokyo", "Peris"]

guessing = input("Please enter your dream city: ")

guessed = False

while guessed == False:
    if guessing in dream_city_list:
        print("You got your dream city!")
        guessed = True
    else:
        print("This city is not in dream city list.")
        guessing = input("Please enter your dream city: ")
```